# Calculating distance travelled by a b2body before it stops in Box2D

Tags: objective-c, box2d, game-physics

I have a zero gravity world. I have a catapult using which a box2d body is shot into space.

I calculate a certain force and apply it to the body along with a certain damping factor.

My code hence looks like this:

```
 _body->ApplyForce(force, b2Vec2(position.x / PTM_RATIO, position.y / PTM_RATIO));
float damping = 1.5f;
_body->SetLinearDamping(damping);
```

I want to calculate the distance it travels before it ultimately stops. What is the correct way to calculate it?

I am calculating it using -

```
distance = force.Length() * (force.Length() / damping)
```

Is that correct?

Comment: Do you want to calculate it before the object is released or after it stops, or while its in air ?

Comment: I want to calculate it before it is released. So that I can show a trajectory path equivalent

Comment: You don't need distance for that. Is it the trajectory you are after ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like its the trajectory you are after. In that case I would recommend having a read through that tutorial. I have implemented that in to a golf game and it work fine for what I needed. Let me know if that answers your question.

[iForce2D Box2D Tutorials - Projected Trajectory](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/projected-trajectory)