# Showing trajectory indicator

Tags: android, box2d, libgdx, physics

[image]

From the image you can see that the ball fired on the left that fire behind it, does not match the calculated trajectory. Im drawing the ball trajectory using an equation from a SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401644/mousejointdef-libgdx-draw-a-trajectory-line-like-angry-birds), this is modified to take into consideration the box2d steps of 30 frames per second. This does calculate a valid trajectory but it does not match the actual trajectory of the ball, the ball has a smaller trajectory. I am applying a box2d force to the ball, this also has a density set and a shape. The shape radius varies depending on the type of ball. Im setting the start velocity in the touchdown event.

```
public class ProjectileEquation {  

    public float gravity;  
    public Vector2 startVelocity = new Vector2();  
    public Vector2 startPoint = new Vector2();  
    public Vector2 gravityVec = new Vector2(0,-10f);

    public float getX(float n) {  
        return startVelocity.x * (n * 1/30f) + startPoint.x;  
    }  

    public float getY(float n) {
        float t = 1/30f * n;
        return 0.5f * gravity * t * t + startVelocity.y * t + startPoint.y;  
    }  



} 

@Override  
    public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float parentAlpha) {  
        float t = 0f;  
        float width = this.getWidth();  
        float height = this.getHeight();  

        float timeSeparation = this.timeSeparation;  

        for (int i = 0; i < trajectoryPointCount; i+=timeSeparation) {  
            //projectileEquation.getTrajectoryPoint(this.getX(), this.getY(), i);
            float x = this.getX() + projectileEquation.getX(i);  
            float y = this.getY() + projectileEquation.getY(i);  

            batch.setColor(this.getColor());  
            if(trajectorySprite != null) batch.draw(trajectorySprite, x, y, width, height);  

           // t += timeSeparation;  
        }  
    } 



public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                if(button==1 || world.showingDialog)return false;
                touchPos.set(x, y);
                float angle = touchPos.sub(playerCannon.position).angle();
                if(angle > 270 ) {
                    angle = 0;
                }
                else if(angle >70) {
                    angle = 70;
                }
                playerCannon.setAngle(angle);
                world.trajPath.controller.angle = angle;
                float radians =  (float) angle * MathUtils.degreesToRadians;
                float ballSpeed = touchPos.sub(playerCannon.position).len()*12;
                world.trajPath.projectileEquation.startVelocity.x = (float) (Math.cos(radians) * ballSpeed);
                world.trajPath.projectileEquation.startVelocity.y = (float) (Math.sin(radians) * ballSpeed);
                return true;
            }



public CannonBall(float x, float y, float width, float height, float damage, World world,  Cannon cannonOwner) {
        super(x, y, width, height, damage, world);
        active = false;
        shape = new CircleShape();
        shape.setRadius(width/2);

        FixtureDef fd = new FixtureDef();
        fd.shape = shape;
        fd.density = 4.5f;
        if(cannonOwner.isEnemy) { //Enemy cannon balls cannot hit other enemy cannons just the player
            fd.filter.groupIndex = -16;
        }
        bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
        bodyDef.position.set(this.position);

        body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
        body.createFixture(fd);
        body.setUserData(this);
        body.setBullet(true);
        this.cannonOwner = cannonOwner; 
        this.hitByBall = null;
        this.particleEffect = null;
    }

  private CannonBall createCannonBall(float radians, float ballSpeed, float radius, float damage)
    {
        CannonBall cannonBall =  new CannonBall(CannonEnd().x, CannonEnd().y, radius * ballSizeMultiplier, radius * ballSizeMultiplier, damage, this.world, this);
        cannonBall.velocity.x = (float) (Math.cos(radians) * ballSpeed);
        //cannonBall.velocity.x = (float) ((Math.sqrt(10) * Math.sqrt(29) *
            //  Math.sqrt((Math.tan(cannon.angle)*Math.tan(cannon.angle))+1)) / Math.sqrt(2 * Math.tan(cannon.angle) - (2 * 10 * 2)/29))* -1f;
        cannonBall.velocity.y = (float) (Math.sin(radians) * ballSpeed);
        cannonBall.active = true;
        //cannonBall.body.applyLinearImpulse(cannonBall.velocity, cannonBall.position);
        cannonBall.body.applyForce(cannonBall.velocity, cannonBall.position );
        return cannonBall;
    }


trajPath = new TrajectoryActor(-10f);
        trajPath.setX(playerCannon.CannonEnd().x);
        trajPath.setY(playerCannon.CannonEnd().y);
        trajPath.setWidth(10f);
        trajPath.setHeight(10f);
        stage.addActor(trajPath);
```

Comment: Have a look here. This might be a better approach to take with the trajectory: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18702564/1464294

Comment: i also tried this method as well, i think something is not matching with box2d. I read in that tut that as long as the start velocity is the same then the trajectory should be correct regardless of mass or density but my case it doesnt match, so something is not right. The radius of the ball changes the distance could it be that these equations dont take that into consideration?

Comment: You are comparing two trajectories. You have shown us the code for one trajectory. How do you calculate the other? Are you sure that the initial velocities and gravities are the same?

Comment: Both are using the method as above in the touchDown event using the angle and ballspeed and some trig. When changing the shape radius the trajectory changes for the fired ball not the trajectory prediction, deoesnt the equation need to take this into account?

Comment: Are you sure that the initial velocities and gravities are the same? Where do you set `gravity`?

Comment: The gravity is set to -10 on the box2d world. Then inside the projectileEquation class to -10. Initial velocity are calculated the same as i explained above.

Comment: I see `gravity` (used but not set) and `gravityVec` (set but not used). You talk about them as if they were the same variable. You expect the velocities to be the same, but you will not check. I can do nothing more.

Comment: Yes gravity is set to -10 via the trajectoryActor class, gravityVec should be removed since its not used.Both im sure are using the same gravity.

Comment: Cross posting: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/62079/showing-trajectory-indicator Perhaps this can be migrated to gamedev and we can close it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a code that I used for one of my other games, which proved to be very precise. The trick is to apply the impulse on the body and read the initial velocity. Having that I calculate 10 positions where the body will be within 0.5 seconds. The language is called Squirrel which is Lua based with C/C++ like syntax. You should be able to grasp what is going on there. What returns from the getTrajectoryPointsForObjectAtImpulse is an array of 10 positions through which the ball will pass within 0.5 seconds.

```
const TIMESTER_DIVIDOR = 60.0;

function getTrajectoryPoint( startingPosition, startingVelocity, n )
{
    local gravity = box2DWorld.GetGravity();
    local t = 1 / 60.0;
    local stepVelocity =  b2Vec2.Create( t * startingVelocity.x, t * startingVelocity.y );
    local stepGravity = b2Vec2.Create( t * t * gravity.x, t * t * gravity.y );

    local result = b2Vec2.Create( 0, 0 );
    result.x = ( startingPosition.x + n * stepVelocity.x + 0.5 * ( n * n + n ) * stepGravity.x ) * MTP;
    result.y = ( startingPosition.y + n * stepVelocity.y + 0.5 * ( n * n + n ) * stepGravity.y ) * -MTP;

    return result;
}

function getTrajectoryPointsForObjectAtImpulse (object, impulse) 
{
    if( !object || !impulse ) return [];

    local result = [];

    object.bBody.ApplyLinearImpulse( impulse, object.bBody.GetWorldCenter() );

    local initialVelocity = object.bBody.GetLinearVelocity();

    object.bBody.SetLinearVelocity( b2Vec2.Create(0, 0) );
    object.bBody.SetActive(false);

    for ( local i = 0.0 ; i < ( 0.5 * TIMESTER_DIVIDOR ) ; )
    {
        result.append( getTrajectoryPoint(object.bBody.GetPosition(), initialVelocity, i.tointeger() ) );

        i += ( (0.5 * TIMESTER_DIVIDOR) * 0.1 );
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you do not understand any part of the code, please let me know and I will try to explain.

Comment: thanks I will try this out later and let you know, its similar to my code but maybe the difference is that you are using GetLinearVelocity() on the body to get the box2d velocity.

Comment: I implemented the code but the trajectories do not match, im using the getLinearVelocity to get the initial velocity after doing the applyImpulse and using the same settings on each ball. The only part that could be different is the equation that box2d uses. Is the equation above correct? Why is gravity applied to the x component, shouldnt that be a constant?

Comment: The equations above are 100% correct, I have used them in games before and the ball follows trajectory to a letter. The X direction gravity is included for completeness.

Comment: ok, do you have an idea why the trajectory does not match, does the equation im using above look correct? What are the MTP variables above?

Comment: MTP is the meter to pixel transition. In case of my application it is equal to 30.

Comment: @tsukimi Interestingly, this is the [same solution](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/62079/showing-trajectory-indicator/62089#62089) I gave you when you asked and abandoned this on gamedev.stackexchange.

Comment: well i got it working , it matches exactly , which was beautiful to see.I think using the getInitialVelocity helped get the right start velocity.Then it wasnt matching because i forgot to convert world positions into screen positions. Your answer pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: @DrewCummins I found this easier to understand and directly related to box2d, the use of getLinearVelocity helped to solve the problem.

Comment: @LemonMooseTom I also want to use "Impulse" to let the object jump in projectile. But how to calculate out the impulse velocity from a known distance and angle? Thx!