# how to force a game object projectile trajectory like angry bird

Tags: java, android, jbox2d

I am a new Android game developer. I want to force my game object which moves to projectile trajectory like in Angry birds.

[Related example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713856/showing-trajectory-indicator/18785062#comment27809934_18785062) and my example You can see image.

[image: here]

I use jbox2d little bit code, but I don't know how to make it work.

```
private static class ProjectileEquation {

    public float gravity;
    public Vector2 startVelocity = new Vector2();
    public Vector2 startPoint = new Vector2();

    public float yogx(float t) {
        return startPoint.x + t * startVelocity.x;
    }

    public float yogy(float t) {

        float u = (float) -4.97741939970554;
        float v = (float) 30.88079;
        float tt = 1/6f;  
        float n = (u+v)/2*tt;

        return startPoint.y + n * t *startVelocity.y + 0.5f *(n*n+n) 
            * t * t * gravity;
    }
}

private static class Controller {
    public float power = -66f;
    public float angle = 585f;      
}
}

public float P2M(float xPixels) {
return xPixels * metersPerPixel;
}

public float M2P(float xMetres) {
return xMetres * pixelsPerMeter;
}

public float MaxHeight(){

 if (projectileEquation.startVelocity.y > 0){

        return projectileEquation.startPoint.y;   
 }
    return projectileEquation.startPoint.y;
    }

public void Update() {
projectileEquation.startVelocity.set(controller.power,controller.power);
projectileEquation.startVelocity.rotate(controller.angle);
 //     bd = bodies;

}



@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
    super.onDraw(c);

    MaxHeight();

    Update();

    float t = 0f;
    x = c.getWidth()/2;
    y = c.getHeight()-20;

    float timeSeparation = this.timeSeparation;    

    for (int i = 0; i < trajectoryPointCount; i++) {

        float x = this.x +  projectileEquation.yogx(t);
        float y = this.y +  -projectileEquation.yogy(t);

        t += timeSeparation;

        if(A) {
            c.drawBitmap(bmp, x, y, null);
        }else if(B) { 

            float bX = M2P(body.getPosition().x);
            float by = c.getHeight() - M2P(body.getPosition().y); 
            body.setActive(true);

            c.drawCircle(bX, by, M2P(body.m_fixtureList.m_shape.m_radius), circlePaint);
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class jbox2d {

    public float targetFps = 30.0f;
    public float timeStep = (1.0f / targetFps);
    private int interations = 2;
    public Body body;
    private World world;
    private BodyDef bodydef;

    public void Create(){

        Vec2 gravity = new Vec2(0,-10f);
        boolean doSleep = true;
        world = new World(gravity, doSleep);
    }

    public void addboll() {

        bodydef = new BodyDef();
        bodydef.type = BodyType.DYNAMIC;
        bodydef.allowSleep = true;


        bodydef.position.set(8.24f,10f);

        body = world.createBody(bodydef);
        body.setActive(false);
        float tt = 0f;     

        Vec2 stx = new Vec2();
        Vec2 sty =new Vec2();

        for (int it = 0; it < 20; it++) { 

            stx = M2P(projectileEquation.startVelocity.x);
            sty = M2P(projectileEquation.startVelocity.y);

            stx = M2P(projectileEquation.yogx(tt));
            sty = -M2P(projectileEquation.yogy(tt));

            body.setLinearVelocity(new Vec2(stx,sty));
            body.applyLinearImpulse(body.getLinearVelocity(), body.getWorldCenter());

            tt += timeSeparation;
        }

        CircleShape circle = new CircleShape();
        circle.m_radius = (float).42;

        FixtureDef fixturedef = new FixtureDef();
        fixturedef.density = 1.0f;
        fixturedef.restitution  = 0.9f;
        fixturedef.friction = 0.2f;
        fixturedef.shape = circle;
        body.createFixture(fixturedef);

    }

    public void update(){
        world.step(timeStep, interations, interations);
    }   
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run your app? What do you want to happen?

Comment: thank for response sar. how to same trajectory point my object(boll) move

Comment: **please give me example code** is not a question - it is a demand that us on StackOverflow are unlikely to fulfill. Please describe to us what is wrong with the current code you've shown and what you attempted yourself to solve that problem.

Comment: sorry for bad edit sar. i want to force a object which move projectile like above code.i don't know how to do.